# Modifying numpy array to get minimum number of values between elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of the form: `arr = 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1`

I would like to modify it such that there are atleast seven 0s between any two 1s. If there are less than seven 0s, then convert the intervining 1's to 0.
I am thinking that numpy.where could work here, but not sure how to do it in a succint, pythonic manner:

The output should look like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

numpy.where(arr[:] > 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: `np.where` won't do it. Considering how inherently stateful the problem is - whether any 1 is erased depends heavily on previous erasure decisions - I doubt there's a good way to do it through NumPy operations.

Comment: thanks @user2357112, so should I revert to for loops then?

Comment: That's one option. You might also try approaches that erase more elements than necessary, or try some really hacky stuff with an appropriate ufunc's `at` method and a rolling window.

Comment: The problem isn't quite well defined. Multiple solutions to the same problem may exist. That is, unless you adopt a 'where two are fighting, two are in the wrong' approach, in which case masking by a convolution with the input would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is a really ugly hack, but it gets the job done in linear time (assuming 7 is fixed) without resorting to Python loops and without needing anything like Numba or Cython. I don't recommend using it, especially if 7 might be 700 next month.

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

arr2 = numpy.append(1-arr, [0]*7)
numpy.power.at(rolling_window(arr2[1:], 7), np.arange(len(arr)), arr2[:-7, None])
arr = 1 - arr2[:-7]
```

It works by setting 1s to 0s and vice versa, then for each element `x`, setting each element `y` in the next 7 spots to `y**x`, then undoing the 0/1 switch. The power operation sets everything within 7 spaces of a 0 to 1, in such a way that the effect is immediately visible to power operations further down the array.

Comment: thanks @user2357112, why would you not recommend your soln for 700 instead of 7? speed concerns?

Comment: @user308827: Speed concerns. This takes `O(window*len(arr))` time, where `arr` is the array you're processing and `window` is how many 0s you need between successive 1s. Also, regardless of speed, this code is hard to understand, bug-prone, and really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Now this is just a simple implementation using for loops and ifs but I am pretty sure it can be condensed.(a lot!) And yeah there's no need to do Numpy for this, it will only complicate things for you.

```
question = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
result = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
indexesOf1s = []
for index,item in enumerate(question):     #Here just calculate all the index of 1s
if item == 1:
    indexesOf1s.append(index)
for i in indexesOf1s:               #Iterate over the indexes and change acc to conditions
    sub = i - indexes[indexes.index(i)-1]
    if sub>0 and sub>=7:
        question[i] = 1
    elif sub>0:
        question[i] = 0
print question 
print result
```